# How does backpropagation work in a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I think I understand backpropagation as a concept.

I Implemented this tutorial: https://www.anotsorandomwalk.com/backpropagation-example-with-numbers-step-by-step

and also this one: https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/

That worked great as long as I had a constant mapping of 1 set of inputs to 1 set of outputs.

However, once I have differing output related to the input like for example an AND gate like this:

```
[
    { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
    { input: [0, 1], output: [0] },
    { input: [1, 0], output: [0] },
    { input: [1, 1], output: [1] },
    { input: [1, 1], output: [1] },
    { input: [1, 1], output: [1] },
]
```

the whole concept falls apart since every time the output is supposed to be 0, all the weights are adjusted towards 0 and likewise if the output is supposed to be 1.

I'm wracking my brain to come up with the missing piece I got here.

how do you make the adjustments of the weights dependent on the input?

Comment: Backprop appears long time ago, and you may just reading some working code from opensource ML libraries such OpenCV ([train_backprop function](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/ann_mlp.cpp)) or try to understand [this solution](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/).